# MySQL - any way to set FOREIGN KEY to NULL?

Tags: mysql

I am making a database for the gym at school and there is 'Open Gym' which does not have an Instructor, however you would register for the open gym as you would any other class. It makes sense that a FK would not be able to be NULL in that it would be a PK in the parent table, but if there is any way around this, any help would be great.

Not sure if I should make an extra table just for the open gym sessions, not sure if that is the most ideal way of going about this.

```
CREATE TABLE `instructor` (
`InstructorID` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
`First Name` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`Last Name` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (InstructorID)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `class` (
`ClassID` DECIMAL(10,0) NOT NULL,
`Name` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`Type` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`Discount Price` DECIMAL(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`Regular Price` DECIMAL(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`InstructorID` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`UnitID` DECIMAL(10,0) DEFAULT NULL,
`CourseID` DECIMAL(10,0) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (ClassID),
FOREIGN KEY (UnitID) REFERENCES subunit(UnitID),
FOREIGN KEY (InstructorID) REFERENCES instructor(InstructorID),
FOREIGN KEY (CourseID) REFERENCES course(CourseID)
) ENGINE=INNODB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: just add allow null on that column

Comment: I set the column to DEFAULT NULL in the 'class' table, however when I insert the values I get 

error: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`groupprojectbtm382`.`class`, CONSTRAINT `class_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`InstructorID`) REFERENCES `instructor` (`InstructorID`))

Comment: did you allow null on it? `InstructorID` in your table `class`

Comment: No I did not, I'll look up how to do that now. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, can you include your sql query also for inserting data, there might be something wrong the way insert the data

Comment: This is part of my 'class' table INSERT query:

    INSERT INTO Class VALUES ('10063','Iaido','Martial Arts','35','55','20000039','000008','0005');
    INSERT INTO Class VALUES ('10064','Badminton','Recreational','30','40','','00001','0006');
INSERT INTO Class VALUES ('10065','Basketball (Pick-up)','Recreational','20','40','','00001','0006');
INSERT INTO Class VALUES ('10066','Basketbal (Outdoors)','Recreational','0','0','','000010','0006');
INSERT INTO Class VALUES ('10067','Beach Volleyball','Recreational','0','0','','000010','0006');

Comment: `''` isn't equal to null, change `''` to null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the cause of your problem because you put an empty value which is `''` instead of null

```
INSERT INTO Class VALUES ('10067','Beach Volleyball','Recreational','0','0','','000010','0006');
```

change `''` to `null`

Comment: @softshellturtle well if this satisfy you and solve your problem, just mark this as answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want the type of data consistency benefits of having a foreign key for the "Open Gym" class that you have for every other class, you can add a dummy row in the instructor table.

Otherwise, if you make `instructor.InstructorId` nullable that will also work